# How to represent 4 boolean possibilities in a single value

Tags: java, byte, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I want to store 4 boolean possibilities in a single value. For example, 
I want a single value that tells whether a person is:

`IsSingle

 IsGraduate

 IsMale

 IsLookingForPartner`

So is it good to store them in a byte, whose 4 bits may be allocated, one for each parameter. If the bit is set to 1 then that boolean parameter is true. So I can do bit shift operations to find what all are true. if value of byte is 111 then first three parameters are true. Is it a good way? Is there a better way to implement this?

I need to store this value as a single parameter in the database.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Bit flags.

```
public static final int IsSingle = 1 << 0;
public static final int IsGraduate = 1 << 1;
public static final int IsMale = 1 << 2;
public static final int IsLookingForPartner = 1 << 3;

...

if ((Value & IsSingle) != 0) {
}

if ((Value & IsGraduate) != 0) {
}

// Set "Single"
Value |= IsSingle;

// Remove "Graduate"
Value &= ~IsGraduate;
```

Answer (score 11):

It is indeed possible to do this, however it is not recommended.

What if you wanted to find in your database all the students who are single? Or Male? 
While the space you are saving is minimal, you are giving up the possibility of indexing your data for faster search not only that, but to find any data which has query criteria depending on any of these attributes, you would need to perform bit shifting operations on all the records (or checking against multiple integer values) which would end up being terribly slow.

The added complexity doesn't really yield much of a benefit in my humble opinion, databases can handle 4 separate fields and there is good reason for doing it that way (e.g querying your data on those fields easily).

Answer (score 10):

You may find that an EnumSet is a natural way to represent this information. An EnumSet uses a bit mask under the bonnet.

```
enum Interest {
   IsSingle,
   IsGraduate,
   IsMale,
   IsLookingForPartner 
}

EnumSet<Interest> interests = EnumSet.of(Interest.IsSingle, Interest.IsMale);
```

You can add any number of enum values.

Answer (score 8):

Use binary packing. Define constants for them as:

```
IsSingle = 1;
IsGraduate = 2;
IsMale = 4;
IsLookingForPartner = 8;
```

And combine them with logical OR operation. That way each possibility will be represented by a bit in the binary representation of a number.You can check by AND-ing the packed value with any of the constants:

```
short status = IsSingle | IsMale;    // will give 5

if ((status & IsMale) != 0)
    System.out.println("Male.");
```

Answer (score 3):

The best would be an `boolean[4]` where you will save each value in different cell of array, and it takes minimum space!

write this piece of code in your class:

```
private boolean[] values = new boolean[4];

void setValue(String name, boolean value){
    if(name=="IsSingle")
        values[0] = value;
    else if(name=="IsGraduate")
        values[1] = value;
    else if(name=="IsMale")
        values[2] = value;
    else if(name=="IsLookingForPartner")
        values[3] = value;
}

boolean getValue(String name){
    if(name=="IsSingle")
        return values[0];
    else if(name=="IsGraduate")
        return values[1];
    else if(name=="IsMale")
        return values[2];
    else if(name=="IsLookingForPartner")
        return values[3];
    else
        return false;
}
```

now just use this like: `setValue("IsGraduate", true);` `getValue("IsMale");`

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using a Byte to store the values? You could then do something like the following:

```
public Byte setDetails(bool isSingle, bool isGraduate, bool isMale, bool isLooking)
{
    Byte result = 0;

    //Set the details
    if (isSingle) result = result | 1;
    if (isGraduate) result = result | 2;
    if (isMale) result = result | 4;
    if (isLooking) result = result | 8;

    return result;
}
```

Then later you can use code like:

```
Byte details = getDetails(true, false, true, false);
bool isSingle = (details & 1) != 0;
```

to get the details.

... That said, for the sake of three bytes, is it worth all the extra work and constants?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.  Its `boolean`, not `bool`, and you also need to replace `result = result | 1` with `result = (byte)(result | 1)` and so on.

Comment: @Luke - My mistake, I whipped it up in a hurry without checking. Should have put a disclaimer on.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the solution just for fun that's OK but if this will be professional application DO NOT implement this in single parameter in database. If you do that think about business' changes:

1. Remove isLookingForPartner //redundant bit will be all the time - order does matter
2. Add new parameters
3. Find all persons who are isLookingForPartner==true //will be slow

Answer (score 0):

You really should use separate variables to store these. A person could be a graduate, single, male, *and* looking for a partner. You simply can't store all those possibilities in a single boolean.